# how to recognise that I am able to log in to rets?

Tags: php, rets

how to recognise i am able to log in to rets ?
This is my code and output.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


//date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

//$log = new \Monolog\Logger('PHRETS');
//$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));

$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('*****************');
        $config->setUsername('****');
        $config->setPassword('****');
        $config->setUserAgent('****');
        $config->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');
        $config->setOption('disable_follow_location',false);
        $config->setOption('use_post_method',true);
$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);

$rets->setLogger($log);

$connect = $rets->Login();

var_dump($connect->getBody());
```

**output**

**Notice:**

> Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/glvar/rets/vendor/troydavisson/phrets/src/Parsers/GetMetadata/System.php
>   on line 26

**Fatal error:**

> Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/glvar/rets/vendor/troydavisson/phrets/src/Parsers/GetMetadata/System.php
>   on line 26

how can i know from this response that i am login in to rets and 
i can get any data.

Comment: File: System.php, line 26, check how do you use member function attributes(), with this error you called it on a non object.. It's fatal error..

Comment: Without defining `$log` nothing is going to happen.

Comment: $log = new \Monolog\Logger('PHRETS');
$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));

i did this now it giving me out put as 

NULL

am i login ?

Comment: @ultrazz008 
anyone of you having any documentation regarding the RETS.

Comment: @RST do you have any documentation regarding the RETS from where i can understand the responses what i am getting from the RETS servers.

Comment: With the errormessages you know you are not logged in. Adjust your code to exactly the code you are using, otherwise it is hard to tell where the error is. Right now your post shows you commented out the `$log` definition which is one reason why things don't work

Answer (score 1):

```
      $config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
    $config ->setLoginUrl(***)
            ->setUsername(***)
            ->setPassword(***)
            ->setRetsVersion(***)
            ->setOption('use_post_method', false)
            ->setOption('disable_follow_location', false);
    empty($user_agent') ? '' : $config->setUserAgent($user_agent); 
    empty($user_agent_password) ? '' : $config->setUserAgentPassword($user_agent_password);
    $rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
    $connect = $rets->Login();
    if ($connect) {
        echo " + Connected\n\n";
        return $connect;
    } else {
        echo" + NotConnected\n\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ever better way to make sure.. add the code below you $connect and you should get something like the below.. and any response not an error should indicate a connection and show you what was returned..

```
$connect = $rets->Login();
print "<pre>";
print_r($connect);
print "</pre>";
```

This will be returned or some thing similar if you are connected..

```
PHRETS\Models\Bulletin Object
    array { 
        [body:protected] => 
    }
```

Watch out on the above answer.. I ran it on a live RETS feed and it stopped my program in its tracks.. and printed + Connected... I removed the return $connect and changed the \n to 
 and it ran fine and printed Connected.. but my point is it may appear to work fine but the program will not go past the connection test... so it killed my program dead in its tracks... not sure why?